# Python: What is wrong with this simple calculation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calculation, tkinter-entry

I don't understand how to solve what is happening with a calculation.

I have a variable `val_var` in my code. I want the value of `val_var` to equal the sum of 2 other variables:

`imp_var = StringVar(value=0)` and
`man_var = StringVar(value=0)`

(note in the full code that the user selects a different value and 0 is just a default value before any selection has been made)

In the gui the user defines a task and some values ('Impact' and 'Manageability').
I want the sum of those values.

I have defined `val_var = str(imp_var)+str(man_var)` which ultimately prints *00*
and also tried `val_var = (imp_var)+(man_var)` which also prints *00*

**EDIT:**

I have defined `val_var = int(imp_var.get())+ int(man_var.get())` but it still prints *0* when i try to print it

**Printing in code:** *Line 26*

**imp_var in code:** *Line 49*

**man_var in code:** *Line 54*

**val_var in code:** *Line 65*

**Full code:**

```
import tkinter.messagebox # Import the messagebox module



task_list = []
task_types = ['Sparetime', 'School', 'Work']

class Task:
    def __init__(self, n, i, m, h, v): 
        self.name = n
        self.impact = i
        self.manageability = m
        self.hours = h
        self.value = v


def show_tasks():
    task = task_list[-1]
    #print(
        #'Task:'+task.name + '\n' +
        #'Impact:' + task.impact + '\n' +
        #'Manageability:' + task.manageability + '\n' +
        #'Hours:' + task.hours + '\n'
        #'Value:' + task.value +'\n'
        #)
    print('Task:')
    print(task.name)
    print('Impact:')
    print(task.impact)
    print('manageability:')
    print(task.manageability)
    print('Hours')
    print(task.hours)
    print('Value:')
    print(task.value)

def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()
    
    #TITLE
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:', font=('Roboto',11,'bold')).grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    #IMPACT
    impactlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Impact', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=0, row=2)
    imp_var = StringVar(value=0)
    OptionMenu(taskwin, imp_var, *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='ns')

    #MANAGEABILITY
    manlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Manageability', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=1, row=2)
    man_var = StringVar(value=0)
    OptionMenu(taskwin, man_var, *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='nsew')



    #HOURS(required)
    hourlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Whole hours \n required', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=1, row=16)
    hour_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=4, justify='center')
    hour_entry.grid(column=1, row=17)

    #VALUE
    val_var = int(imp_var.get())+ int(man_var.get())
        
    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '': # If textbox inputfield is NOT empty do this:
            task_list.append(Task(name_entry.get(), imp_var.get(), man_var.get(), hour_entry.get(), val_var))
            show_tasks()
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, name_entry.get())
            name_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')

        
    next_button = Button(taskwin, text='Next', font=('Roboto',10), command=add_task).grid(column=2, row=18, sticky="ne")
    
def sort_tasks():
    pass
def delete_task():
    try:
        task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
        listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Error', message='You must select a task to delete')

def save_tasks():
    pass

    


    
    
    
    

root = Tk()








task_frame = Frame()
# Create UI
your_tasks_label = Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()


scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(root, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center') # tkinter.Listbox(where it should go, height=x, width=xx)
listbox_tasks.pack()

listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)


#BUTTONS
Add_Button = Button(root, text='Add New', width=42, command=open_add_task)
Add_Button.pack()

button_delete_task = Button(root, text='Delete task', width=42, command=delete_task)
button_delete_task.pack()


button_save_tasks = Button(root, text='Save tasks', width=42, command=save_tasks)
button_save_tasks.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `int()` instead of `str()`?

Comment: Yes, it returns an error ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str```

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator, when applied to strings, is string concatenation (joining). When applied to numbers, it's addition.

So `"4" + "2"` gives `"42"` but `4 + 2` gives `6`.

So, if you want addition, you need to turn your strings into numbers. Python has a function that will do that for you, such as with:

```py
num1 = "4"
num2 = "2"
print(num1 + num2)           # outputs 42.
print(int(num1) + int(num2)) # outputs 6.
```

Comment: I tried already `val_var = (int(imp_var.get()))+ (int(man_var.get()))` which gives an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: @KarimLoberg: it is impossible to get that error from the code in that comment since the things being added are both numerics, not strings.  Since the line in your original code also adds `hour_entry.get()`, you may want to ensure that one is also made into a numeric.

Comment: I found the reason, it was because i was trying to print a string + ```val_var``` somewhere else in the code.

I have corrected it and updated the code in my question, but it just returns *0*